# jQuery scrolltop if/else/and from a different page?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery script on my site to scroll down on blog entry pages from a comments link at the top to the actual comments at the bottom:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
       var TopPosition = jQuery('#comments').offset().top;     
       jQuery('.comments-link').click(function(){        
           jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:TopPosition}, 2000, 'swing');
           return false;
       });   
   });
```

I'd also like the page to scroll down to "#respond' when '#comments' does not exist. Is this possible somehow in jquery with an if/else/and?

Also, is it possible to link from a different page with a comments link (i.e. my blog's index page) to the individual blog entry's comments and also have the animated scroll down?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to scroll to `#respond` when `#comments` doesn't exist, just check the length of the object returned by the selector... if it is 0 then it's not on the page, and you can use the `offset().top` of `#respond` instead.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var comments = jQuery('#comments');
   var TopPosition = (comments.length==0)? 
       jQuery('#respond').offset().top :
       comments.offset().top;     
   jQuery('.comments-link').click(function(){        
       jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:TopPosition}, 2000, 'swing');
       return false;
   });   
});
```

To scroll down on page load, you would need to use a hash (for example `page.php#comments`), however traditionally you would have an anchor tag (`<a name="comments'></a>`), and the page would just jump to it. If you want to have a smooth scroll, you can look at `location.hash` and then trigger the scroll. Since it is effectively the same as the `onClick` I would break it out into a function that you can call for both:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Set up the onClick() event
    jQuery('.comments-link').click(scrollToComments);

    // If the page is page.php#comments scroll to the comments/response
    if (location.hash=='#comments') scrollToComments();
});

// This function handles the scrolling on page load and onclick
function scrollToComments(){
    var comments = jQuery('#comments');
    // this can be moved outside the function, or recalculate in case the page redraws
    var scrollTopPosition = (comments.length==0)? 
       jQuery('#respond').offset().top :
       comments.offset().top;
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollTopPosition}, 2000, 'swing');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Updated to include scrolling to the comments when the `location.hash` matches `#comments` - you can use this to link from other pages.

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thanks so much! I was trying to figure this out the whole day :D

Comment: Hi Doublesharp - I was wondering if you knew if it was possible somehow to also scroll to #comment-NUM where "NUM" could be any number e.g. <div id="comment-21">?